# Loopback: Multiple owners for a model with belongsTo relation

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am new to loopback. I am trying to learn & implement ACL.

I have one "PersistedModel" named 'Page'. I am using two different models as 'Employee' and 'Customer', both based on built-in 'User' model.

Relation:
A page belongs to an 'Employee' as well as a 'Customer'. Both should be owners for a page. Customer & Employee both has many Pages. So, I have added following in relations:

```
    "customer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    },
    "employee": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Employee",
      "foreignKey": "employeeId"
    }
```

ACL:
I want 'WRITE' permission only for owners. So, I have added following in acls:

```
   {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
```

When I try a patch request, owner customer's request gets executed successfully. But, owner employee's request gets 'Authorization error'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you checked the database has correct data for foreign keys?

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani  Yes. I have checked it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LoopBack documentation is updated recently and they have added these two lines in a notice: (http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-built-in-models.html#user-model)

> LoopBack does not support multiple models based on the User model in a single application. That is, you cannot have more than one model derived from the built-in User model in a single app.

So basically, I should not have created two different models those are based on 'User' model. :(

Comment: That has long been changed, see here: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Authentication-authorization-and-permissions.html
`
 From this point you should be able to use LoopBack access control over multiple user models extending the built-in User model
`

Answer (score 1):

Loopback only checks for one owner relation [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/304ecc4784c927be69caaa01a1b7344b169f0fa9/common/models/role.js#L256).

For two owner you need to write your own custom role and register by [role resolver](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html#dynamic-roles)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try with role resolver.

Comment: Wow, this is the shortest but still the most valuable answer found here on SO ever! Thank you Ebrahim, I will try to follow this style.

Answer (score 1):

As loopback said, you should one extend model from User model, define role (from Role model), and assign role to any user or participant via RoleMapping model (it's built-in model).

for example:

1. Extend model from user model and named to MyUser.
2. Create 'Customer' and 'Employee' role.
3. Add relation:

   `"customer": {
     "type": "belongsTo",
     "model": "MyUser",
     "foreignKey": "customerId"
   },
   "employee": {
     "type": "belongsTo",
     "model": "MyUser",
     "foreignKey": "employeeId"
   }`
4. in MyUser model, add the following ACL:

   `{
         "accessType": "WRITE",
         "principalType": "ROLE",
         "principalId": "Customer",
         "permission": "ALLOW"
       },
       {
         "accessType": "WRITE",
         "principalType": "ROLE",
         "principalId": "Employee",
         "permission": "ALLOW"
       }`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, in this solution, any 'Customer' would be able to edit any record. $owner role allows only if user Id is associated with particular record.

Comment: Right! you can [https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html#dynamic-roles] role resolver or custom remote method and enable modify, if authenticated user is owner of record.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this commit](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/commit/e17132d06182e421b3da9a5544f68fc04c61ea17#diff-733982793c3bd5e61d1a4350451fb494) (loopback 3.13.0 released on Sept 28, 2017), you can set `{ownerRelations: true}` to